# Permission error when accessing database/storage in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I updated my code to `10.5.0` version of firebase in my web app (I'm using alternative approach which I got it from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/alt-setup)), but I keep facing permission errors even though my code was working fine without permission error before I attempted to upgrade to `10.5.0` (I was using `8.2.0`).
Here's my `upload.js` file:

```
import {initializeApp} from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.5.0/firebase-app.js';
import {
    getStorage,
    ref as storageRef,
    uploadBytesResumable,
    getDownloadURL,
} from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.5.0/firebase-storage.js';
import {getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, signOut} from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.5.0/firebase-auth.js';
import {getDatabase, ref as databaseRef, push, set} from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.5.0/firebase-database.js';

// all data below is correctly put
const app = initializeApp({
    apiKey: '',
    authDomain: '',
    databaseURL: '',
    projectId: '',
    storageBucket: '',
    messagingSenderId: '',
});

const auth = getAuth(app);
const database = getDatabase(app);
const storage = getStorage(app);

$('#addNew').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var file = $('#pic').prop('files')[0];
    const fileExt = $('#pic').prop('files')[0].name.split('.').pop();
    const fileName = `${getRandomString(15)}.${fileExt}`;

    var listStorageRef = storageRef(storage, `list/images/${fileName}`);
    var uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(listStorageRef, file);

    uploadTask.on(
        'state_changed',
        function (snapshot) {
            // progress being handled here
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log(error); // doesn't log anything
            showMessageByID('Unknown error occurred.', '#message');
        },
        function () {
            getDownloadURL(listStorageRef).then(function (downloadURL) {
                const listRef = databaseRef(database, 'list');
                const newRef = push(listRef);

                console.log(downloadURL);

                set(listRef, {
                    name,
                    // there are other data here
                })
                    .then(function () {
                        const id = newRef.key;
                        // some other operations here
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log('Error object:', error); // for some reason this is not logging the permission error
                        showMessageByID(error.message, '#message'); // this is logging
                    });
            });
        },
    );
});
```

I import `upload.js` like this:
`<script type="module" src="js/firebase/upload.js"></script>`

database security rule:

```
    "list": {
        "$id": {
            ".write": "newData.child('createdBy').val() == auth.uid",
            ".read": false
        },
        ".indexOn": "createdBy"
    },
```

Comment: Can you share the exact error message?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec `error.message` is showing `PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied`

Comment: That error message makes it seem that the user doesn't have permission to write the file. You'll want to check the [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security) you have set, and then in your code explicitly check each of the conditions that your security rules impose.

Comment: I see now that you also write to the Firebase Realtime Database, which also has [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security). So you'll first want to determine which of the write operations is failing, and then check the rules for *that* product.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen But how was this working before without any issue? I doubt it's related to security rules, since it was working before. I think there's something wrong with the way I'm importing the files and firebase variables, maybe there's somewhere that firebase isn't recognizing that the user is actually logged in or something. Maybe I'm forgetting to pass the auth object somewhere? I don't know. As far as I know I'm doing everything fine.

Comment: This error usually comes from the security rules on the Firebase servers, so that's what I'd check first. Did you check which line is causing the error? Did you check the corresponding security rules?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen `showMessageByID(error.message, '#message');` this is logging the error, which is the catch statement of getDownloadURL(), I also tried regularly fetching data on a separate function, and the same `PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied` error occurred. Could it be that the new Firebase version accepts a different way of writing for security rules? Because as I said, it was working fine before, it still is (it's in production right now)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Also I just checked the storage rules and there is no specific rule set for the storage, only for `allPath=**` which is `allow read, write: if request.auth != null;`

Comment: `showMessageByID(error.message, '#message')` seems to be called from the `catch` for the `set(listRef, { name,... })` call to the Realtime Database, so you'll want to check your Realtime Database security rules for the `/list` node.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I updated the post with the security rule for `/list`, this was working fine before, I don't think it has anything to do with the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `set` on the `list` node in your database, yet your rules don't provide any permission to write that node. From the rules you shared it looks like your want to allow adding a new child node under `list`, in which case you'll want to call `set` on `newRef` instead of on `listRef`.

Comment: Thank you Frank. Appreciate your patience with the unnecessary mistakes we make.